# MVVM and RxSwift for Search Screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, mvvm, uisearchbar, rx-swift

In purpose of education MVVM and RxSwift I want to build simple search screen, which will have a table view and a search bar. When user types something into the search bar I will show what he have in this table. Sounds pretty simple, but I can't find any tutorial which suits me.

I have already written all code in view controller, I just can't understand have to observe search text changes and then call database method, which will filter items by search text.

Some code, which I already have.

My ViewController

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class PlaceSearchViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: - 

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    //MARK: - Dependencies

    private var viewModel: PlaceSearchViewModel!
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    //MARK: - Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        viewModel = PlaceSearchViewModel()
        addBindsToViewModel(viewModel)
    }

    //MARK: - Rx

    private func addBindsToViewModel(viewModel: PlaceSearchViewModel) {

        searchBar.rx_text.bindTo(viewModel.searchTextObservable)

        viewModel.placesObservable.bindTo(tableView.rx_itemsWithCellFactory) {
            (tableView: UITableView, index, place: Place) in

            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as PlaceCell

            cell.configureWithObject(place)

            return cell

            }
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

        tableView.rx_contentOffset
            .subscribe { _ in
                if self.searchBar.isFirstResponder() {
                    _ = self.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
                }
            }
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    }
}
```

And my view model:

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class PlaceSearchViewModel {

    //MARK: - Dependecies
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    //MARK: - Model

    private let placesObservable: Observable<[Place]>
    var searchTextObservable = Variable<String>("")

    //MARK: - Set up

    init() {

        placesObservable = searchTextObservable.asObservable()
            //wait 0.3 s after the last value to fire a new value
            .debounce(0.3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
            //only fire if the value is different than the last one
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            //convert Observable<String> to Observable<[Place]>
            .flatMapLatest { searchString -> Observable<[Place]> in

                // some code here which I can't write.

            }
            //make sure all subscribers use the same exact subscription
            .shareReplay(1)
    }

}
```

Also, I have method `[DataBase searchPlaces:searchText]` which returns array of places - `[Place]`. I can't understand where and how place it in `flatMapLatest` of my ViewModel.

Comment: Did you check the [RxExample](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) project in RxSwift repo?

Comment: @KhanXc yes. I don't want to use their RxDelegates for now. Too much new frameworks. That's why I want to find solution without them.

Comment: Some of the delegates are built in(unless your are using RxDatasource). The wikipedia image search code from RxExample will suit your purpose.It using drivers instead of observers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create reactive wrapper for my DataBase by creating Observable<[Place]>.

This is my code

```
placesObservable = searchTextObservable.asObservable()
            //wait 0.3 s after the last value to fire a new value
            .debounce(0.0, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
            //only fire if the value is different than the last one
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            //convert Observable<String> to Observable<Weather>
            .flatMapLatest { searchString -> Observable<[AnyObject]> in
                return TPReactiveDatabase.sharedInstance.searchPlacesByTitle(searchString)
            }
            //make sure all subscribers use the same exact subscription
            .shareReplay(1)
```

And wrapper method `searchPlacesByTitle`

```
class TPReactiveDatabase: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = TPReactiveDatabase()

    // MARK: - Reactive Place database

    func searchPlacesByTitle(title: String) -> Observable<[AnyObject]> {
        return Observable.create { observer in

            var places = [AnyObject]()

            if (title.characters.count > 0) {
                places = DBAccessKit.searchPlacesByTitle(title)
            }

            observer.on(.Next(places))
            observer.on(.Completed)

            return AnonymousDisposable {

            }
        }
    }
}
```